# Put focus back in the search box after doing a search

Tags: feature-request, search, user-experience

After doing a search, the search box doesn't have focus and there's no cursor. I do a lot of searches and many times I want to modify the search terms after a search. It's a better UX if I don't have to use the mouse and put the cursor in there manually every time.

Comment: I agree with this suggestion. The only question is, *which* search box should we put the focus to? The one you originally typed in (at the upper-right corner), or the new one that appears at the top of the results?

Comment: @CodyGray I think a practical way could be to use source of the event, in which the keypress/keydown event happened.

Comment: I would prefer it to be optional.  I still hope that, one day, they will implement the keyboard shortcuts on that page, and if they do, I'd rather be able to navigate the search results using the J/K buttons rather than them being entered into the search box.

Comment: @Code Source of event is fine. On a side note, I always use the big search box. I never understood why there are two of them. I guess there's a question here that explains why.

Comment: @g00glen00b optional how and why? Search box can get focus and user can still be able to use the keyboard to navigate. Next key can go to the first result.

Comment: @Tony_Henrich you use J & K keys to navigate, if you have focus on the search box, the "J" and "K" will be entered in the search box. But this is pure hypothetically speaking, since the keyboard shortcuts do not work yet on the search page. And how: with a checkbox or so if in your preferences.

Comment: @g00glen00b I suggest you tab out of the box and then use those keys. I don't think they want that granular type of settings. I see only a single setting for whether to enable keyboard shortcuts.

Comment: @Tony_Henrich well, you would lay the focus on that field for UX matters, but in my opinion navigating through the search results is the primary action on the search result screen, not having to search again, so I don't think that it should have the focus. Eg. if you search something on google, the search field isn't focused either. If having the focus on the search field would make it harder to navigate through the page using keyboard shortcuts (hypothetically), then I would prefer it being able to be configurable.

Comment: @g00glen00b It takes 23 tabs to get to the first search result on SO, 15 tabs or Google. I don't understand how you find keyboard navigation helpful like this. However on Bing it takes a single tab and it skips everything before it. Helpful but breaks default web accessibility. User has to shift-tab all the way back to the search box. I am saying hit the tab to get out of the search box. I don't see why this is a big keyboard navigation issue. It can be a preference. Anyway I noticed the smaller text box gets a copy from the big box and is accessible after a single tab.

Comment: @Tony_Henrich I'm not talking about tabbing, I'm talking about https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/237166/announcement-keyboard-shortcuts-are-now-integrated-into-the-site. This would conflict with your feature request if these shortcuts would be enabled on the search page.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly what you're looking for, but you can use keyboard navigations to focus on the search bar. Not ideal but still pretty fast. At the time of writing and on Edge browser it takes 2 tabs to focus on the search bar. If you've previously focused on another element, you can use F10 to focus on the menubar, from there it's 3-4 tabs to get to search bar, depending on your menu bar items and the current visiting webpage. (Unfortunately this won't work on other browsers, that I know of)